# Affine plane curves classification

Tags: geometry, polynomials, ideals, algebraic-curves, affine-geometry

Define an affine plane conic as $\operatorname{Spec}A$ where $A=k[x,y]/(f)$ and $f$ a quadratic polynomial with no multiple factors.

Define an equivalence relation on the set of alline plane conics by: two conics are equivalent if tere is a polynomial change of variables that maps one conic to the other one. How do I describe the set of equivalence classes under this relation? I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: You could follow any standard approach classifying conics in $\Bbb{R}[x,y]$, for example in https://www.math.utah.edu/~wortman/1060text-coc.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to think algebro-geometric machinery to do that classification. I think mathematicians classified them before the introduction of those monsters :)

Comment: and btw I thing @san 's reply is more than enough.